# Ubuntu 18.04 stopped showing desktop after running update

Tags: boot

My 18.04 was running fine before this. After I hit restart, all I get is a black screen starting with

```
/dev/sda1: clean ...
[OK] Created slice User Slice of gdm.
     Starting User Manager for UID 120...
[OK] Started Session c1 of user gdm.
....
....
```

and ends with

```
    Starting Disk Manager
[OK] Started GNOME Display Manager. Dispatcher 
         Service....d before the ppp link was shut 
              down....
```

No reaction whatsoever from any keyboard key except <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd>.

Comment: Sometimes this have to do with the Display Manager (gdm). So Previously, I would reinstall Unity or gnome.. Press *Alt-Tab-F2* and `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gnome`

Comment: After pressing Alt-Tab-F2 several times, I suddenly got the Desktop login panel; logged in, opened a terminal, executed suugested commands. Then I restarted and got back to the original problem. Tried Alt-Tab-F2 again; took me to old tty login on first attempt; but login plus pwd yield nothing whatsoever. Have to power off, power on, wait for the "Started GNOME Display Manager ..." message, Alt-Tab-F2 and back to tty login.

Comment: can i see a screenshot of the error page. you can use your phone- Try reinstall your default windows manager(am sure its unity) and `sudo apt-get install lightdm`

Comment: Cannot access the computer so do not know how to give you a screenshot; back to square one. Turned computer on, waited for as long as it took for the whole raft of msgs I mentioned earlier finally appeared; only then Alt-Tab-F2 and desktop login appeared! Logged in, installed lightdm as suggested, and restarted. Takes a long time with black, but after some prodding with the keyboard the desktop login is up again. I'm gonna leave it at that until someone produces some software update to solve this problem. Thanks for your help, saviour123.

Comment: I actually meant ctrl+alt+f2. >>> Did you run any update/upgrade before restarting?

Comment: If yes then. then the solution: boot into recovery mode, you would see two kernels there, boot with the older one.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue when I tried to boot Ubuntu 18.04 a few minutes ago.

Comment: I found this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1779827